# Let $M$ be a non zero maximal ideal in $\mathbb C[x].$ Prove that there exists $a\in \mathbb C$ such that $M=\langle x-a\rangle$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $M$ be a non zero maximal ideal in $\mathbb C[x].$ Prove that there exists $a\in \mathbb C$ such that $M=\langle x-a\rangle$ (ideal generated by $x-a$).

Attempt:

As $\mathbb C[x]$ is a PID, therefore $M=\langle p(x)\rangle$ for some $p(x)\in \mathbb C[x]$.

As $\mathbb C$ is algebraically closed $p(x)$ will have all it's zeros in $\mathbb C$

Thus, $p(x)=(x-a_1)(x-a_2)\cdots(x-a_n)$

Then $M=\langle x-a_i\rangle$ for all $1\le i\le n$

Am I correct ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first three lines of your attempt are perfectly fine.

The fourth line is - strictly speaking - also correct (since we will have $n=1$ anyway, and then it is correct *a posteriori*), but you lack an argument.

Notice that $M=\langle p(x) \rangle \subset \langle x-a_1 \rangle$. But $M$ was assumed to be maximal, hence we must have equality, so $M=\langle x-a_1 \rangle$ (and in particular $p(x)=x-a_1$ up to multiplication with a constant).

Comment: Okie, and this we can do using any of the $a_i's $ , right?

Comment: Strictly speaking, we can't. You cannot make sure (and in fact it is not the case), that there is some $a_2$, so you should not rely your argument on $a_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is right. You only have to observe that $<x -a_i>$ is maximal or, equivalently, that $x-a_i$ is irreducible. 
But it follows, since $\frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{(x-a_i)}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: The fact that $\langle x-a \rangle$ is maximal, is neither needed to proof the statement of the question, nor is it sufficient to do so.

Hence the observation that $\langle x-a \rangle$ is maximal is useless, when you want to to show the statement of the question.

Comment: @MooS you're right. I've realized that after posting the answer.